# Logic in Razorview?

Tags: razor, logic

I have a foreach loop in a view that display a list of files (pictures - ). What I would like is to make some logic inside razor, that would display another  tag if the files arent jpg/png. Something like (pseudo code) :

```
foreach (var file in Model.Files)
{
        if (file.FileExtension == "jpg" || file.FileExtension == "png")
        {
             //markup do something
        }
        else 
        {
            //markup do something else
        }
}
```

This is ofcourse not possible. (Or is it haha?).
Any ideas how I can implement that logic in to the model or controller layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problem?
Assuming that you've got a list of filenames (strings):

```
@foreach (var filename in files)
{
    if (file.EndsWith("jpg") || file.EndsWith("png"))
    {
         <div class="markup-a">@file</div>
    }
    else 
    {
        <div class="markup-b">@file</div>
    }
}
```

Comment: haha yeah I dont see any problem either. Figured it out myself. I just missed the EndsWith when going through the list.